# What platform and software stack is Bing running on?

Tags: bing

What's the famous Bing running on? Asp.net, asp.net mvc, IIS 7, .net 3.5? Using firebug, I thought I could tell what was powering Bing since I had noticed the speed difference between that and Live.com. But, unfortunately, looking at the HTTP headers in firebug yield no server side information. So, what do you think.

Comment: Famous? I don't think something is famous until it becomes a household name with your mother.

Comment: I think he was being tongue-in-cheek; it made me smirk.

Comment: Actually, my mom asked me the other day "Have you used Bing yet?  I really like it!"  I was floored.

Comment: I tried to send them a support ticket but it tried making me sign into one of their services. I got scare and command-w'd outta there.

Answer (score 7):

Mystery solved - one one of the top 5 sites on the planet runs on MVC/IIS.

ScottGu confirmed it during the keynote last week at MvcConf:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2011-Scott-Guthrie-Keynote

Comment: He mentions it at the 52nd minute for those want to save sometime :)

Answer (score 4):

Netcraft [says](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=bing.com) an unknown web server running on Windows 2003 (www.bing.com says Linux, but also notes that www is run by Akamai). Being Microsoft, this is a little suspicious, but also consider none of Microsoft's existing stack seems to lend itself particularly well to the highly specialized realm of Google-level search. In this particular case, Microsoft does seem to place higher priority on getting something out there that actually works (unlike Live.com) than with product synergy.

Comment: When I checked Netcraft, it said that bing.com was running on F5 Big-IP (http://www.f5.com/products/technologies/). However, this might only be what's running in the front but we can surely assume that this site is not build on one of the technologies mentioned by the OP (In fact I wouldn't expect to find any standard server software there at all).

Comment: I thought Big-IP was a switching Brouter?  I didn't think that it was an applications host?

Comment: @divo edited to clarify.

Comment: Where's "the Hanselman" when you need him? He's somewhat active here. I think he could get us the dirt. 8^D

Comment: Server 2003 is a surprise to me if true.  I would have bet Server 2008.

Comment: If the detection mechanism that Netcraft is using works correctly, then they don't use Windows Server but F5 Big-IP (as already said). However, it lists the domain having used Windows Server 2003 before it was owned by Microsoft (see "Hosting History").

Comment: I can't say explicitly, but I can say you wouldn't be surprised what it's running. I'm working on getting permission to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

[httprecon](http://www.computec.ch/projekte/httprecon/?) shows a 100% match with `Microsoft IIS 6.0` for what that's worth.

edit: [direct link](http://w3dt.net/tools/httprecon/?host=www.bing.com&submit=Analyze)

Answer (score 0):

Bing.com published a bunch of graphs and data about what powers it. Basically it's a regular ASP.NET MVC application. Shows to you how performant managec code can be.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2012/06/07/bing-com-runs-on-windows-server-2012.aspx